# When do domain and forestprep

Tags: windows, domain, controller

I have a simple domain with a single Win2003 server.  I just upgraded the funcitonal level to Win2003.

I am now trying to add a Win2012 DC, but it warns me that the functional level is still at w2000

I upgraded it 5 minutes ago, with a single DC, do I have to wait longer?  Is something else going on?

Do have have to prep the domain and forest BEFORE I add the win2012 DC?  Or after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you raise the Domain functional level or the Forest functional level? You need to raise the Forest functional level to Windows 2003. Forest prep and Domain prep will run during the Windows Server 2012 DCPROMO process.